# How to save a Mongo document's own _id in a nested field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to copy the newly created property `_id` into a sub document but failed to do so.

How can it be done?

**edit:**
The code uses `matb33:collection-hooks`.

```
MyCollection.after.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  if (doc.element === 'myString') {
    doc.values[0]._id = doc._id;
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using something like https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks?

Comment: @AnthonyAstige Yes. post updated.

Comment: Why not generate an `_id` when inserting the document? This will eliminate the need to run those additional queries.

Comment: @MasterAM great idea, never tried it before, does it have to be in all documents being inserted in this collection or can it be just for this insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutating the `doc` in the `after` hooks of `matb33:collection-hooks` will not cause additional queries to be run. You will need to explicitly `update` the document if you wish to do so.

However, in this particular case, if you really need the duplicate `_id` in the document, you could generate an `_id` and specify it when inserting the document.

You can probably use `MyCollection._makeNewID()` method, as this API has not changed for a few years and it is what the `Mongo` package uses internally.

```
const _id = MyCollection._makeNewID();
const doc = {
  _id,
  values: [
    {
      _id,
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }
  ]
};

MyCollection.insert(doc);
```